# Radial Schrödinger equation of a scattering in two dimentions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, notation

The scattering, in two dimensions, of a particle of mass $m$ by a central potential $U(r)$. The hamiltonian of the system is $H= p^2/2m + U(r)$.

Then the radial wave function $ϕ(r)$ is obtained as a solution to
$$((d^2/dr^2)+1/r(d/dr)-(v^2/r^2)+K^2)ϕ(r)=0.$$

where $v^2(L)=L^2+2mλ$,  $K^2=2mE$,  if $U(r)=λ/r^2$.

My first question is why the author chose the separation of variables constant to be $L^2$, where we usually take it as $L(L+1)$? and the second term of the equation i think is $2/r$ not $1/r$?

Comment: ON SCALE INVARIANCE AND ANOMALIES IN QUANTUM
MECHANICS∗
A. Cabo†, J.L. Lucio and H. Mercado, page 6

Comment: Permalink: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9702042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in two dimensions, so the free
Schroedinger equation has $E=k^2$
solutions
$$
\psi(r,\theta) =e^{il\theta}J_l(kr),\quad  l\in {\mathbb Z}
$$
The  radial equation is Bessel's equation which  has $l^2/r^2$ rather than $l(l+1)/r^2$.