# Derivation of Poisson bracket and commutator of position and conserve charge

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, poisson-brackets

How can I prove these two relations? Assuming $\mathbf{D}$ is defined as $$\mathbf{D}=\sum\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{x}_i}\delta x_i-\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{H}t-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{r}$$
we have
$$\{x_i,\mathbf{D}\}=\dot{x}t-\frac{1}{2}x_i\{\dot{x}_i\,\mathbf{D}\}=\ddot{x}_i t+\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}_i$$
$$[x_i,\mathbf{D}]=\dot{x}t-\frac{1}{2}x_i[\dot{x}_i\,\mathbf{D}]=\ddot{x}_i t+\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}_i$$

When i do the calculations, I don’t get another term

Comment: It would be helpful to extract the relevant part where you have trouble from the paper and write it out in your question to make it self-contained.

Comment: Another q about the same paper: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/585164/2451